# Missing param from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I m posting an array along with a variable in ajax like

```
$.post(pageURL,{data:data,id:linkid},function showData(Data)
{

})
```

at pageURL the data object is accessible but the id is missing . I tried pushing that id in data array like

```
data['id']=linkid
```

but still i cant manage to get that id at pageURL (though i can see that "id" posted in my call header). On pageURL i am trying to get values using 
`print_r($_REQUEST['data']['id']);`

my request headers are
[image]

Comment: is `data` an object ?

Comment: yes. its a object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why but just shuffling the places like

```
$.post(pageURL,{id:linkid,data:data},function showData(Data)
{

})
```

solved the issue. if anybody can explain why it solved like this it would be helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add id in your data object. like this

```
 data['id']=linkid
```

Then post it in ajax request.

```
 $.post(pageURL, { data: data }, function showData(Data) {

       });
```

Then you will be able to access it using data object.

```
$_REQUEST[data[id]]'
```

Complete code.

```
 data.id = linkid;
       $.post(pageURL, { data: data }, function showData(Data) {

       })
```

Comment: i tried it. it is in object on js file . but after post on my pageurl it is not in the data .

Comment: @nOmi : what is pageUrl?
and also share your browser console network tab. see I'm geeting this. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTzPF.png)

Comment: it is a php file where i am processing the data.

Comment: i can see that id posting in my call headers . but it is not on my process page .

Comment: @nOmi: Try to access it like `$_POST[data[id]]'`

Answer (score 0):

To get the id you simply do

```
print_r($_POST['id']);
```

if this doesn't work you can try to change the name of the value

```
{data:data,linkid:linkid}
 print_r($_POST['linkid']);
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the xhr header?

Comment: specifically the bottom part

Comment: headers attached in question

Answer (score 0):

Try to access $_POST['data']['id']

Comment: i think it won't make any difference . $_REQUEST will have all .